# How to install asterisk on Mac os for pjsip

Tags: ios, macos, asterisk, pjsip

Does any one know how to install asterisk on mac? I am new to voip so please guide me from basics like what software/ command line tools would be needed.
I do tried to search it on google but couldn't found any doc with the proper steps. You can also provide link of tutorial. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## Try brew it yourself [brew asterisk](https://github.com/leedm777/homebrew-asterisk)

1. minor issues in asterisk.rb and pjsip-asterisk.rb during brew
2. change "<<-EOS.undent" to "<<~EOS" as suggest by brew solve the problem

-

```
xcode-select --install
brew tap leedm777/homebrew-asterisk
brew install asterisk
```

Answer (score -1):

For novice in voip, recommended way is start virtulization system on your choice, run asterisk in container.

Not think you can find really upto-date tutorial for install asterisk on non-linux OS(windows,osx,solaris or linux-risk,linux-ARM, whatever). Such install required expert level on destination OS.

Comment: why vote down for the answer and question, if you know the answer then please help